# is there a javascript multi maps source api?

Tags: maps, bing-maps, openstreetmap

I looking for an API that can manage some api keys of different map sources like google maps, openstreetmaps and other providers with a common language.

The goal is to write something like the following and work across multiple maps sources

```
map.source = commonMapSource.Sources.GoogleMaps;
var placemark = commonMapSource.Overlays.Placemark;
placemark.setMap(map);
```

Is there something like what I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created something like this a long time ago for Bing and Google maps. These types of wrappers are not common anymore as the map controls change too fast. Also, it's often against the terms of use of the map providers to mix data with other maps. For example using coordinates from Bing Maps geocoder can not be used in Google Maps. If you are looking for a single map control that you can switch the data providers in take a look at OpenLayers: http://openlayers.org/

Answer (score 2):

Actually yes, although I'm not exactly sure if it has been kept up-to-date with the latest API changes from all the providers.

It's called Mastraction: http://mapstraction.com/

Supposedly supports (copy&pasted directly from the site above)

- CloudMade
- ESRI ArcGIS
- Google – v2 and v3
- Leaflet
- MapQuest and MapQuest Open
- Microsoft Bing – v6 and v7
- Nokia Here
- OpenLayers
- Ordnance Survey OpenSpace
- Nokia Ovi
- Yandex

I did try it a couple of years ago and worked well enough for simple stuff.